# How to change path separator in makefile variables

Tags: makefile

I have to following bit of code in my makefile:

```
SRC_DIRS = . folder

MAIN_CXX_FILES=${foreach d,${SRC_DIRS},${wildcard ${d}/${strip ${EXE_PREFIX}}*.cpp}}

COMMON_CXX_FILES=${filter-out ${MAIN_CXX_FILES},${foreach d,${SRC_DIRS},${wildcard ${d}/*.cpp}}}
```

Here my two `MAIN_CXX_FILES` and `COMMON_CXX_FILES` variables do exactly what I want them to do (grab all .c and .cpp files from the folders specified with the `SRC_DIRS` variable) but the path to a file in 'folder' (in the `COMMON_CXX_FILES` variable)  look like this `folder/file.cpp` whereas I would like it to look like `folder\file.cpp`

I have tried the following but it doesn't work

```
COMMON_CXX_FILES=${foreach d,${COMMON_CXX_FILES},${subst /,\,${d}}}
```

Comment: Try `:=` instead of `=`. Also you don't need `foreach`, you can process the whole list at once.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a useful problem report.  Please show (cut and paste, with formatting, not paraphrased) the command you typed and the output you got and, if not obvious, what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (replace space with comma separator).

```
LST:=file1 file2 file3
WITH_SEP:=$(shell echo $(LST) | sed 's/ /,/'
```